# How to enforce referential integrity on the one side of a many-to-one relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

Those are my models:

```
class Hero(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class Photo(models.Model):
    hero = models.ForeignKey(Hero)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='heroes')
```

Now, according to the rules of this app, a `Hero` must not be created without at least one `Photo`. I've spent 4 hours combing the docs and I'm yet to find a solution. If this were Rails, it'd be simple:

```
class Hero < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hero
```

With my Django models, the fields make sure that a `Photo` can't be uploaded without a `Hero` — which is what I want — but a `Hero` can be created without a `Photo` — which is not what I want, I'd like to enforce at the database level that a `Hero` has at least one `Photo`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: you could do this with a custom ModelForm where you set photo as a required field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to do this at the database level, and your Rails code certainly does no such thing. This is not a limitation of either Django or Rails, but simple logic; a Photo can't be created without the ID of a Hero, which means the Hero must already be created - without a Photo - first.

The only way to do this, in any application, is in business logic at the point where Heros and Photos are created. In Django, you do that through forms - a modelform for Hero with an associated inline formset for Photo. The validation logic for the modelform would then be responsible for ensuring that at least one Photo was created.